# Standard Sign for custom Javascript Library

Tags: jquery, javascript

jQuery uses $ (dollarsign), is there a **standard sign** one can use for my own custom library? So that anyone would understand it's custom?

Sometimes I only need to getEmementById and class, and be able to addclass and maybe a few more simple things. And I would like to do it like $('#someId').addClass('foo'); but **I would like for others who view the code, and myself, to understand that it is a custom library**, not jQuery. So, is there a standard sign for this?

EDIT: I could use a namespace, but thats not as pretty as a single sign. And I cant see why there isn't one out there allready that has been used by many before for this purpose. Isn't there one?

Comment: No... You can use `_`, though.

Comment: _ looks ugly, and namespaces consists of more than one sign(?)

Comment: @Nile [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) already uses this @ Mathias what is your problem with using one or two letters for your namespace?

Comment: No.. you can use **any** and it does not need to be a sign. It may be a shortname, abbreviation or whatever as long as it's a valid variable name.

Comment: say it to underscore developers :)

Comment: And I would like for anyone that reads the code to understand its a custom library. Not to wonder.

Comment: why not use your initials `ms` or `_$` or `ಠ_ಠ` if you like - just be creative.

Comment: Developers will know what they put in their code. If the developer placed jQuery in the code, the developer expects that the `jQuery` and `$` namespaces is the jQuery library. So if you used the `$` namespace, but no jQuery script was loaded on to the page, `$` should be something else.

Comment: @Christoph I was just hoping there was a standarised sign for this. Seems like it isnt. Good point on underscore tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function must have a valid variable name. 
Therefore, according to the spec a variable names can start with $, _, lower case/upper case unicode etc.

It's probably best to use the module pattern inconjunction with IIFE though.

IE if your library was assigned to a variable 'myLibrary'

```
var myLibrary = (function() {
  return {
     someFunction: function(){ ... };
  }
})()
```

And you could then pass it into an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) and give it your own variable - for instance using JQuery's $

```
(function($) { 
    $.someFunction();
})(myLibrary);
```

Because of the scope precedence of `$` you'll have no problem doing this - Unless of course you want to make use of jQuery

Comment: I could of course create any namespace I want to. Or I could just use $, but a namespace isn't as pretty, and $ would confuse people.

Comment: Then your alternative is a `_` if you don't want to confuse people. Making use of the second pattern I gave is nice, as you can define your own variable to take precedence over anything else which may have been defined - IE if you use `_` then you don't want to have conflictions with the underscore.js library

Comment: Ok, so _ is the least confusing? But it will not work with underscore.js?

Comment: @Alan `_` might confuse people as well (and lead to collisions), as it is the common usage for underscore.js - see my comment on the question.

Comment: It looks like the answer to my question is NO! But this is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of your library:

```
myLibrary('#someId').addClass('foo');
```

There will not be any confusion this way. Bear in mind that `$` is just an alias to the `jQuery` function and youhave the possibility to redefine it in case you want to [use it with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: Yes, I could. But a namespace isn't the same as a single sign.

Comment: You should at least have a namespace. Then if you want you could map it to a custom sign if you will. There's no established convention for that.

Comment: Yes, sure. But unfortunately that does not answer the question. I might have been unclear, so I updated the question.